# Convert comma separated string into json array

Tags: bash, shell, string, array, json

I have the following string in `bash`

```
"3.8,3.9,3.10"
```

Is there a way using shell to convert it into a `json` array, i.e.

```
["3.8", "3.9", "3.10"]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the string (including its double quotes) seems to be a properly formatted JSON string, we could pass it, as JSON, to the JSON processor `jq` and split it on the commas:

```bash
$ echo '"3.8,3.9,3.10"' | jq 'split(",")'
[
  "3.8",
  "3.9",
  "3.10"
]
```

Use `jq` with `-c` to get "compact output":

```bash
$ echo '"3.8,3.9,3.10"' | jq -c 'split(",")'
["3.8","3.9","3.10"]
```

Giving it to an internal `jq` variable on the command line and then splitting that variable's value:

```bash
$ jq -c -n --argjson str '"3.8,3.9,3.10"' '$str|split(",")'
["3.8","3.9","3.10"]
```